# concurrent insertion with unique key constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, unique-key

I have a web application with multiple instance running all connected to a p-SQL with a table - `myTable` that have only two columns with one column is having unique key constraint.

This application will receive at least 15K request in a second from multiple instance and my requirement is to avoid the duplicate insertion in the table.

myTable:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
myData VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE);
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myData) VALUES ('data-1');
```

My question is if all the instances try to insert same data (assume the above insert statement from all the instances), all at a time to the table will I get only one record inserted and one instance will get inserted success message and all other instance will get a duplicate key error?

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO myTable (myData) VALUES ('data-1') on conflict do nothing;` to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Yes, the other INSERTs will receive an error (as soon as the first INSERT is committed). If you don't want that use `on conflict` as Stefanov suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It actually answers my requirement. It's great to know that PSQL handle concurrency with unique key constraint. Thank you.

Comment: Just a slight correction. PSQL is not handling the concurrency, it is a client side application (command line but still a client app). It is the Postgres DBMS that handles it.

Comment: Watch out - `on conflict do nothing` will consume IDs from your serial anyway, also in case of conflicts.